# How to achieve midpoint rounding away from zero in numberfield in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, rounding, extjs6.2

I'm dealing with ExtJS 6.2.1. I have a numberfield and need to limit it to three digits after a separator. So I use a decimalPrecision property:

```
{ xtype: 'numberfield', decimalPrecision: 3 }
```

Now, it seems that by default ExtJS uses midpoint rounding to the closest even number:
1.2345 turns into 1.234 and 1.2355 turns into 1.236.
I need to change this behaviour to round away from zero, so that 1.2345 turns into 1.235.
How can I achive this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This action takes place in the private [fixPrecision](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Number.html#method-fixPrecision) method.

```
        return parseFloat(Ext.Number.toFixed(parseFloat(value), precision));
```

I think the reason that it doesn't round as you expect, is that it's actually stored as a number slightly less than 1.2345 and it rounds down. This is due to the ways of storing floating-point numbers in RAM

To fix the component’s work, I suggest using the following override

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.field.NumberOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Number',
    fixPrecision: function (value) {
        var me = this,
            nan = isNaN(value),
            precision = me.decimalPrecision;
        if (nan || !value) {
            return nan ? '' : value;
        } else if (!me.allowDecimals || precision <= 0) {
            precision = 0;
        }
        return (Math.round(value * (10 ** precision)) / (10 ** precision)).toFixed(precision);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34qr)

P.S. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary) helped me

Comment: Thank you for answer. Haven't tried it, but it seems legit. I resolved my problem by setting decimalPrecision: 4 and adding a listener like that: listeners: {
      'change': function(field, newValue, oldValue) {
       newValue = Math.round(newValue * 1000) / 1000;
       field.setValue(newValue);
      }
     }